# Can't install win32gui

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install win32gui with pip but I get an error:

```
C:\Users\משתמש>pip install win32gui

Collecting win32gui
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/75/7bed82934e51903f9d48b26b3996161bb2dce1731607b4bb7fd26003ed3e/win32gui-221.5.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... done
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\temp\pip-install-ycidig8u\win32gui\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
from win32.distutils.gui import win32gui_build_ext
File "c:\temp\pip-install-ycidig8u\win32gui\win32\distutils\gui.py", line 6, in <module>
from .command import win32_build_ext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.distutils.command'
----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\temp\pip-install-ycidig8u\win32gui\
```

I'm using python 3.7
I've upgraded the setuptools but it is still not working...

Comment: It may be trying to build the extension and you don't have something required to do that. I usually get a pre-built version from [Christoph Gohlke's UCI web site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Just search for "PyWin32",

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Install pywin32. That gives you win32gui.

`pip install pywin32`

Comment: Above command working for me on my windows 11 system. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Win32gui isn't compatible with 3.7.

3.7 was realeased in 2018 and the latest version of win32gui was released in August 2017.

I would suggest installing 3.6 or lower as a workaround.

#### EDIT:

The answer by @bronson beat me to it by 9 days, but installing `pywin32` with `pip install pywin32` will install `win32gui` alongside modules for interfacing with windows.

Answer (score 1):

See this link: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32). It may be of help to you.

```
Step 1: Download the pywin32....whl
Step 2: pip install pywin32....whl
Step 3: C:\python32\python.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Step 4: python
>>> import win32gui
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All your needs you will satisfy in the module ctypes.
Use it and you won't have any compatibility issues.

For example:

```
import ctypes
EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
GetWindowThreadProcessId = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, types.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible
IsWindowEnabled = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowEnabled
```