# win32gui installation through pip failure

Tags: python, installation, win32gui

I failed to setup win32gui. First, I typed pip install win32gui on the terminal, but it said Command ~ failed with error code 1 in ~. So I find out some installation information on the internet.

I have updated tools such as pip, easy_install. And I also tried to setup with whl. I'm using 64bit computer and 32 bit python. So I tried to setup 64bit and also 32 bit but none of them worked. I'm new to python and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you paste in the actual traceback of `pip` and tell us if you installed python for all users, if so, are you using pip in a administrative console or not?

Comment: Even if you have a 64-bit system, if you are using 32-bit Python you *must* stick to 32-bit distributions. Doing anything else will simply not work and give you more puzzles, not solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install win32gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806906/cant-install-win32gui)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 3.7.4 64-bit and it seems that I got the same error.

win32gui can only support up to Python 3.6 and it does **NOT** support Python 3.7.

I used pywin32 and solved this.

PS: Here is what modules my script imports:

```
import sys, os, psutil, clipboard, win32process, win32gui, win32api, time
```