# How to install 'win32gui' with `pip`?

Tags: python, win32gui

Im testing out someones code and I can't import `win32gui` its really annoying.
I have tried in **cmd** `pip install win32gui` and it comes up with

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'

I am using pycharm, python 3.8 on windows 10

Comment: Have you installed it? [`pip install win32gui`](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/) Otherwise, what's your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I think the module you actually need is called `pywin32`.

Comment: To add onto what @jordanm said, it seems that win32gui is known as/has become pywin32 since late 2017.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install win32gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806906/cant-install-win32gui)

Comment: This question is essentially same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806906/cant-install-win32gui/52812481. The reason the install fails is because `win32gui` is not compatible with `python 3.8`. To resolve the issue, you may either downgrade your python version to `3.6` and then do `pip install win32gui ` **OR** with your current python version run `pip install pywin32` and it should ultimately install `win32gui`.

Answer (score 3):

Enter this at the command prompt

**pip install pywin32==300**

Then **import win32gui** will work with python 3.8.

Comment: Or just `pip install pywin32`

Answer (score -1):

PyCharm can be configured to work in an isolated python environment.
To be sure to install it for the project environment, follow [this document from PyCharm editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).