# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui

Tags: python

sorry for potentially asking stupid questions but I am newbie, learning Python from YT videos.

I need to use Ptwin32 extension, and use the libraries there.

- EDIT: using Windows 10
- Dowloaded "pywin32-300.win-amd64-py3.9" from here "https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases"
- Using python 3.9.1 and PyCharm 2020.3.1.
- On the beginning of my program I write:

  import win32gui 
  import win32con

and then I get the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'"

Tried to search for solutions but nothing worked so far.

Thx in advance for help.
Loonak

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: yes, sorry, just edited.

Comment: Looking at setup.py I see dist = setup(name="pywin32", ... Have you tried using that name? And the same name is in the instructions https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/README.md which say "pip install pywin32"

Comment: did u use `pip`?

Comment: yeah, so I just learned about pip :). So I installed python from Windows Store, then installed pip, then installed these exnension. Now it's importing the libraries in PythonWin but still not in PyCharm. I tried to reinstall the python package from the executable python-3.9.1-amd64 but didnt help. So - my main problem seems to be solved (I can work with PythonWin), now I need "only" to make PyCharm see this. Ideas?

Comment: Saying `pip` install PythonWin should be in PyCharm because PyCharm is just a IDE so all the installation that you do outside should be global (unless if its a virtual env). So does it still give you a error even when you say `import pywin32` in PyCharm?.

Comment: yes. I think I should create separate question for that?

Comment: ok, I simply used Pycharm "problems" tab to install it :). Worked, thanks for all your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem & `py -m pip install win32gui` didn't solve it,
finally it was fixed using `py -m pip install pywin32` as *@Kenny Ostrom* advised

Comment: now I see that its mentioned already in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60309475)

Answer (score -1):

Go to your terminal and say either `pip install win32gui` or `pip3 install win32gui`(Try the other one if one of these 2 don't work)

Happy Coding!