# failed to install win32gui

Tags: python, pip, win32com

I tried installing win32gui from pip and i get this error, any fixes? any issues? i think we have to install some other module before installing this?im not sure. im using python 3.7. pls help, thanks in advance :)

Code :

`pip install win32gui`

Error :

```
Collecting win32gui
  Using cached win32gui-221.5.tar.gz (605 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\nihaa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzpwt8q58'
       cwd: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9htmy1u1\win32gui
  Complete output (20 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 240, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 91, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rhxhgo5i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 148, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rhxhgo5i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 128, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rhxhgo5i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 250, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rhxhgo5i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
      from win32.distutils.gui import win32gui_build_ext
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9htmy1u1\win32gui\win32\distutils\gui.py", line 6, in <module>
      from .command import win32_build_ext
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.distutils.command'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzpwt8q58' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install win32gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806906/cant-install-win32gui)

Answer (score -1):

win32gui isn't compatible with 3.7.

Try a lower version of python

Comment: like ver 3.6?but my whole proj is part of 3.7 nd even the modules